# how do I make function keys switch to different terminals in console mode?

Tags: linux, terminal, arch-linux, console, function-keys

Without running any window manager, just logged in directly to the box in the first terminal session, how can I make F2, F3, F4, etc switch to other terminal "tabs"?

i.e. not using screen or tmux

I seem to remember old unix systems doing this from years ago, but is this still possible with a base arch linux system today?

Comment: It is possible as long as those TTY are started. The shortcut you're looking for is CTRL+ALT+F2, F3, F4, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is called a Virtual Terminal aka `VT`

Most distributions support switching to a different VT with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> , <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, etc

A graphical environment (X-window) is just one of those VTs, often 6th or 7th.

To switch *from* an X-Window session to another VT you need to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, e t.c. (unless this is forbidden through `novtswitch` option)

I don't remember bare <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, etc ever switching VTs, but you can make them behave like that. Enter following from a root text VT (X-window terminal emulater won't do):

```
#loadkeys
keycode  59 = Console_1
keycode  60 = Console_2
.......
keycode  69 = Console_10
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to finish input

To reapply those changes on reboot, save above to a file and refer to your distro documentation on keymaps, such as [this page on ArchLinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Extra_keyboard_keys_in_console#Saving_changes)